# How can I order a series of api calls from the frontend?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a series of API calls I need to make from a 'user profile' page on my app. I need to prioritize or order the calls when I land on the component.

I have tried using async-await on the componentDidMount lifecycle method but when the first call fails, the rest do not get called.

```
...

async componentDidMount() {

  await user.getGameStats();
  await user.getFriendsList();
  await user.getPlayStyle();

}

...
```

Despite ordering the calls, I would like them to still execute regardless of whether the preceding calls failed.

Comment: Did you use await fetch function for getting the user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to account for rejected promises. If you don't catch the error it will stop execution. Just add a `catch()` block to each function that may fail.

```js
function a(){
  return new Promise((r,f)=>{
    console.log('a');
    r();
  });
}

function b(){
  return new Promise((r,f)=>{
    console.log('b');
    f(); // rejecting this promise
  });
}

function c(){
  return new Promise((r,f)=>{
    console.log('c');
    r();
  });
}

async function d(){
  throw new Error('Something broke');
}

(async ()=>{
  await a().catch(()=>console.log('caught a'));
  await b().catch(()=>console.log('caught b'));
  await c().catch(()=>console.log('caught c'));
  await d().catch(()=>console.log('caught d'));
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a dirty solution, but you can do something like this:

```
user.getGameStats().then({res => {
  callGetFriendsList();
}).catch({err => 
  callGetFriendsList();
});

function callGetFriendsList() {
  user.getFriendsList().then(res => {
    user.getPlayStyle();
  }).catch(err => {
    user.getPlayStyle();
  });
}
```

The ideal and good way would be to call all of them at the same time asynchronously if they are not dependent on the response of the previous request.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty catch at the end of each API call as following

```
async componentDidMount() {

  await user.getGameStats().catch(err=>{});
  await user.getFriendsList().catch(err=>{});
  await user.getPlayStyle().catch(err=>{});

}
```

Comment: Since async/await is supposed to act like it's synchronous, it would be better form to use `try {await user.getGameStats()} catch(_) {}`

Comment: @Ian He wants to prioritize  or order then as he said in question that's why they need to be synchronous.

Comment: what I sent does exactly the same thing; it just looks more standard for the async/await form.

Comment: he doesn't really want to handle any of the error so I think it won't matter if we add try or not,will it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd `catch` to `null`:

```
  const nullOnErr = promise => promise.catch(() => null);

 async componentDidMount() {
   const [gameStats, friendsList, playStyle] = await Promise.all([
     nullOnErr(user.getGameStats()),
     nullOnErr(user.getFriendsList()),
     nullOnErr(user.getPlayStyle())
    ]);
    //...
 }
```

I also used Promise.all to run the calls in parallel as there seems to be no dependency between the calls.